# If $u$ is a solution of $F(x) \cdot \nabla u = h(u) $ and $F(x) \cdot v(x)>0 \forall x \in \partial U$ then $u\equiv 0$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

> Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open and bounded; $0 \in U $ and $\partial U$ is smooth. Let $u \in C^1(\bar{U})$ be a solution of the equation
> $$F(x) \cdot \nabla u = h(u),$$
> with $F:\bar{U} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ continuous satisfying $F(x)\cdot v(x)>0, \forall x \in \partial U$, where $v(x)$ is the normal unit vector exterior to $\partial U$. If $h$ is a decreasing function and $h(0) = 0$ then $u \equiv 0$.

I have to solve this (yes, it is my homework, I signed up to some classes and I don't have the prerequisites and so I'm lost in almost everything I have to do. Please help me **learn**. I might need to know something very basic but I'm missing that piece of information).

Now, given thet $\partial U$ is smooth I can use the divergence theorem on this. So far I have this:

$$\int_U \nabla\cdot F(x) dx = \int_{\partial U} F(x) \cdot v(x) dx >0,$$
As $h$ is decreasing and $h(0)=0$ I know $h(x)\leq 0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and so
$$0\geq\int_U h(u(x))dx = \int_U F(x)\cdot \nabla u(x) dx = \int_U \nabla\cdot [F(x)u(x)]dx - \int_U [\nabla\cdot F(x)]u(x)dx$$

So $$\int_U \nabla \cdot [F(x)u(x)]dx \leq \int_U[\nabla\cdot F(x)]u(x)dx$$

How do I carry on? I get that I should find something on the lines of: "on one hand, on $\partial U$ we have that $F(x)\cdot v(x)$ is always positive, on the other $h(u(x))$ is never positive, so $u$ must be $0$ everyhere".

But I don't know how to do so. Thanks in advance.

---

Tips provided by the professor today (haven't tried it yet, but I'll post it here already in case someone wants to give it a try as well).

This is just my recollection of what he said in class, it is in no way formally written:

The function u is $C^1(\bar{U})$ and therefore has a maximum (and minimum) value somewhere in $\bar{U}$. Now we have two cases, either the maximum (and minimum) is inside $U$ or is in the boundary $\partial U$.

We'll talk about the maximum but the result follows similarly for the minimum.

If u has it's maximum in $x \in U$ then we have that, at the maximum the gradient of $u$ is $0$. and so
$$h(u(x)) = F(x)\cdot \nabla u(x)  = F(x) \cdot 0 =0$$

as the function $h$ is decreasing, and $h(0) = 0$, we have that $u(x)$ must be $0$, as it is the only place where $h$ assumes the value $0$.

and so the maximum of the function $u(x)=0$. Similarly we find that it's minimum is also $0$, so $u \equiv 0$.

If on the other hand the maximum(and minimum) is on the boundary, then we have a problem. The professor sugested using "Lagrange multiplier" to solve this part.

I have **no clue** what a lagrange multiplier is, but I'll read and after I learn it I believe I'll be able to solve the rest.

Comment: Even if it is your homework, I am happy with your effort, +1. Which class did you sign up to, for which this was the homework? Which chapter are you studying, and from which book? This is important so someone can read up that chapter and see if they can do it with the tools from that chapter, which is probably the intention.

Comment: The course is just called "Partial differential equations". When this homework was assigned we only had seen the first chapter of Fritz John's book "Partial differential Equations".

The professor gave some tips today, I haven't tried them yet, but I'll edit the question to add the new information.

Comment: Thank you very much for the additional information, it should be helpful to anybody trying to answer the question (includes me)

Comment: @Matheusbarroscastro FYI, a Lagrange multiplier is a technique used in constrained optimization. See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)

Comment: There are some things I need to clarify. First, is $\overline{U}$ the interior of $U$ ? Also, from the beginning equation, it appears that $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, but you have written


">>As $h$ is decreasing and $h(0)=0$ I know $h(x)\leq 0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$<<"

$h$ is supposed to take a scalar argument, but now it's taking in a vector? Please clarify.

Comment: $\bar{U}$ is meant to be the closure of $U$. And I'm sorry, it was a typo, it was meant to be $h(x)\leq 0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. I'll edit the question to fix it.

Comment: Also, your statement "on the other hand, $h(u(x))$ is never positive... " is not correct. If $u(x)<0$, $h(u(x))$ could be positive. Take for instance the decreasing function $h(t)=-t$. It is positive for negative arguments.

Comment: You're right. For some reason I was under the impression $h: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and that's why I said $h(x)$ is never positive, as $\|x\|>0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$. My bad, got confused in my own vague notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have a solution. Fix me if I am wrong.

There are two different options:

1. $u$ has it's maximum in $x_{\max} \in U$ we obtain that $u(x_{\max}) = 0$
2. $u$ has it's maximum in $x_{\max} \in \partial U$.

Consider the second case:

As far as $\partial U$ is smooth we can choose such function $g(x) \in C^1(\bar{U})$ so that $\partial U = \{x \, |\, g(x) = 0\}$ and the normal vector $\nabla g(x)$ to $\partial U$ will be external hence $\nabla g(x) = \alpha v(x)$ where $\alpha > 0$. So now we can apply Lagrange necessary conditions for a constrained extrema:
$$\exists \lambda: \,  \nabla u(x_{\max}) = \lambda \nabla g(x_{\max})$$
By multiplying left and right part of the last equation by $F(x_{\max})$ we will get:

$$ F(x_{\max}) \nabla u(x_{\max}) = \lambda F(x_{\max}) \nabla g(x_{\max})$$
$$ h(u(x_{\max})) = \lambda \alpha F(x_{\max}) v(x_{\max})$$

By the condition of the problem $F(x_{\max}) v(x_{\max}) > 0$

Let $\lambda \geq 0$ then: $h(u(x_{\max})) > 0 $ which is impossible because $h$ is decreasing and $h(0) = 0$ hence $h(x) < 0$.

So $\lambda < 0$. Which actually mean that $\nabla u(x_{\max})$ is interior normal of the $\partial U$.

Hence if $h > 0$ we obtain that vector ($x_{\max} + h \nabla u(x_{\max})) \in U$. Since $x_{\max}$ is maximum of $u$:

$$ \frac{u(x_{\max} + h \nabla u(x_{\max})) - u(x_{\max})}{h} \leq 0$$

Going to the limit we will get the directional derivative of $u$ at $x_{\max}$ along the vector $\nabla u(x_{\max})$

$$ 0 \leq \nabla u(x_{\max}) \cdot \nabla u(x_{\max}) = \lim_{x \to 0+} \frac{u(x_{\max} + h \nabla u(x_{\max})) - u(x_{\max})}{h} \leq 0$$

Which means that $\nabla u(x_{\max}) = 0$ which is impossible. Thus we got that $x_{\max} \in U \implies u(x_{\max}) = 0$.

Doing similarity for $x_{\min}$ we conclude that:

1. if $x_{\min} \in U$ we obtain that $u(x_{\min}) = 0$
2. if $x_{\min} \in \partial U$ we obtain that $h(u(x_{\min})) = \lambda \alpha F(x_{\min}) v(x_{\min}) < 0$. But since $h$ is decreasing we get $u(x_{\min}) \geq 0 = u(x_{\max})$.

It both cases we get $u(x_{\min}) = u(x_{\max}) = 0$ which implies $u \equiv 0$.

Comment: "As $\partial U$ is smooth, we can choose $g \in C^1(\bar{U})$ such that $\partial U =\{x : g(x) =0\}$" : can you justify this? I thought smooth boundary meant that at each point there was a locally defined function which determines the boundary. By compactness that gives us finitely many $g_n$ smooth which work on the boundary, but how do you make this one function? I think the rest of the proof makes sense.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon there is often a lot of confusion in defining smoothness. Personally, I assumed that the smoothness of $\partial U$ means that there is $C^1$ mapping between $G \subset \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ to $\partial U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ or something like "exist $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})$ that $x_n = f(x_1, ..., x_{n-1})$ . It that case it's obvious that such implicit function (I mean $g(x)$ from the solution) exists which defines the surface $\partial U$.

Comment: Very true, Eugene.  The bigger problem is, I looked up Fritz John, and I could not find any definition of a smooth domain. So I'm confused as well. But +1, because apart from that everything is right, and we can sort that part out I am sure, if the definition isn't what you say it is.

Comment: Quick tip: `\min` and `\max` print $\min$ and $\max$.